# Java: el texto escrito en un archivo y el leido de ese archivo son diferentes

Tags: java, archivo, filereader

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en Jetbrains academy llamado [Work on project. Stage 2/4: Saved and loaded](https://hyperskill.org/projects/38/stages/202/implement)  que es parte del proyecto de [creación de un editor de texto](https://hyperskill.org/projects/38?goal=7).

Obtengo el siguiente mensaje con una prueba:

> Wrong answer in test #18
>
> Text should be the same after saving and loading same file

creoq ue se debe a esta parte el enunciado del problema que dice traducido:

Ahora, agreguemos trabajar con archivos. Para cargar un archivo desde disco duro, el usuario debe especificar el nombre del archivo existente. Si ejecuta esto desde un IDE, este archivo debe estar en la misma carpeta donde está la carpeta "src". Luego, después de que el usuario presiona el botón "Cargar", el contenido del archivo debe mostrarse en el campo de texto. Después de editar, debería poder guardar el archivo. Para hacerlo, debe especificar un nombre para el archivo y luego presionar el botón "Guardar".

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Este es mi código:

```
package editor;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TextEditor extends JFrame {
    public TextEditor() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setName("TextArea");

        JTextField txtFilename = new JTextField();
        txtFilename.setName("FilenameField");
        Dimension filenameFieldSize = new Dimension(135, 20);
        txtFilename.setPreferredSize(filenameFieldSize);
        txtFilename.setMinimumSize(filenameFieldSize);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.setName("SaveButton");

        JButton btnLoadFile = new JButton("Load");
        btnLoadFile.setName("LoadButton");

        JScrollPane scrlTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrlTextArea.setName("ScrollPane");
        JPanel topComponentsPanel = new JPanel();
        topComponentsPanel.add(txtFilename);
        topComponentsPanel.add(btnSave);
        topComponentsPanel.add(btnLoadFile);


        btnLoadFile.addActionListener((evt) -> {
            try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFilename.getName()))) {
                String readedContent = fileReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
                textArea.setText(readedContent);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
        btnSave.addActionListener((evt) -> {
            try (BufferedWriter fileWritter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(txtFilename.getName()))) {
                fileWritter.write(textArea.getText());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        add(topComponentsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scrlTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("Text editor");
        // pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextEditor te = new TextEditor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo revisaría los fin de linea, que no estuviera cambiando \r x \n o formato \r\n por otra \r o \n. Y si eso no funciona, hace una copia del archivo original y luego comparalo a nivel de bytes contra la nueva versión a ver donde están las diferencias.

Comment: @Juan pues ya lo resolví, justo hice eso antes de darme cuenta del `txtFilename.getName()` así que no sé qué fue lo que lo resolvió de las dos cosas.